# Batch script for moving files older then x days from one location to another based on modified date excluding some files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'am working on batch scripting for specific purpose.
My requirement is to move files older then particular days (modified date) from one location to another.

Using following script :-

```
@echo off  
set "src=C:\move_file_1_loc_2_another\In"
set "dest=C:\move_file_1_loc_2_another\Out"
 for %%F in ("%src%\*.*") do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tF") do (
        if not exist "%dest%\%%A" mkdir "%dest%\%%A"
            forfiles -p "%src%" -d -2 -m *.* /C "cmd /c move "%%~fF" "%dest%\%%A"" 
    )
 )
```

The script successfully moves the files leaving behind some extensions. Let me make it more clear.

Above scripts says to move all files older then 2 days but system also moves some files of last 2 days and some files are left out from moving.

My need is that it should exclude all the files of last 2 days no matter what the extension of the file is.

Please suggest where I'am going wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: What about changing the option `-d -2` of `forfiles` to `-d -3`? And you need to fix the quotation using `0x22` to include `"` in the command line of `forfiles /C` like this: `forfiles -p "%src%" -d -2 -m *.* /C "cmd /c move 0x22%%~fF0x22 0x22%dest%\%%A0x22"`

Comment: Hi @aschipfl - whats the purpose of changing -2 to -3. My problem is not days . The problem is that it moves some files of previous days also whereas I want no single file should be moved if I write -2 that means no single file (any extension) should be moved from directory of last two days  

*File types that I have right now in system is - .txt and .72x and system is moving .txt files and leaving .72x files but i want script to leave both .txt and .72x files in system and move away rest all the files

Comment: Because you said you want to move files *older than* 2 days, and `-2` includes items that are 2 days old. Anyway, I still don't get what you want. You are talking about certain file types (extensions), but your code does not reflect them. Perhaps it would help to include some example data in your question...